# Listbox does not show items c# xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, templates

i have written this in xaml:

```html
 <ListBox x:Name="WorkersList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding gehalt}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Then i wrote a c# class called "worker" and added the follwing code to the mainpage.cs:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{



    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<Worker> sourceworkerlist = new List<Worker>();
        sourceworkerlist.Add(new Worker { name = "Franz", gehalt = 200 });
        WorkersList.DataContext = sourceworkerlist;
    }
}
```

I ran the program but the result is I dont see the listboxitem :( what did i do wrong? Thx for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `DataContext` in your code behind as posted, then your XAML should look like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="WorkersList" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Worker}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding gehalt}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the complete XAML file:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication11" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="WorkersList" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Worker}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding gehalt}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but i get an error in the xaml - im building for windows 10 universal platform: type is not supported ... how do i need to change the data context?

Comment: I edited my answer and posted the entire XAML file content. You may be missing some xml namespace (xlmns). Check your XAML against mine.

Comment: It works by leaving the datacontext code line out, i already declared it in c# -> look above ;)

Comment: I noticed that, but for me it works even keeping DataContext in... I used a normal WPF project for Windows 8.1 and you're using a Windows 10 universal app... that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind ItemsSource to DataSource, or set ItemsSource in the code.

```
WorkersList.ItemsSource = sourceworkerlist;
```

or

```
<ListBox x:Name="WorkersList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann No you didn't do neither of the solutions I suggested, you don't have `ItemsSource="{Binding}` nor `WorkersList.ItemsSource = sourceworkerlist;`

Comment: Oh sry (it has over 35°C here ;) i overread it, youre right sry